# Que son las ObservableList y en donde puedo utilizarlas?

Tags: java

Comienzo a programar en java y no me ha quedado claro las listas observables, he visto ejemplos donde donde las relacionan con un ArrayList pero no entiendo que fin tiene esa relacion.

Comment: Por favor indica el código o lugar donde viste de este recurso. Eso ayudará más a comprender tu problema/pregunta.

Answer (score 4):

La interfaz `ObservableList` es una interfaz de lista de [JavaFX](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/collections/jfxpub-collections.htm), y se usa `FXCollections` para equipar una lista con la funcionalidad adicional.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.collections.ListChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;

public class EjemploObservableList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Se insta una lista.
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        // se agrega la observación usando FXCollections:
    ObservableList<String> observableList = FXCollections.observableList(list);
        observableList.addListener(new ListChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onChanged(ListChangeListener.Change change) {
                System.out.println("Ocurrio un cambio! ");
            }
        });

        // Se reportan cambios a observableList.
        // Aquí se va imprimir la alerta 
        observableList.add("uno");

        // cambios directas a la lista escapan la observación
        // no se imprime ninguna alerta 
        list.add("dos");

        System.out.println("Tamano: "+observableList.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: te deje una edicion, en tu respuesta espero no te molestara, pense que seria util para el OP. Saludos

Comment: Si, Luiggi lo revertió al estado anterior me parece. Si se trata de los tildes en el código, eso no es un gran drama, porque Es bien posible de usar utf-8 en archivos de Java (hay que configurar la IDE como corresponde no más). Mientras lo uso en cadenas, en el peor de los casos hay caracteres que no se muestran bien.

Comment: No lo de las tildes fue para que pudiera comprobar como funcionaba el codigo en un ide online y en el ide propuesto que admitia javafx no funcionaba con tildes ect, ademas le mencione lo del JDK, pero aun asi para intentar no manchar mucho su pregunta le deje el codigo oculto, le dije mas o menos lo mismo en el campo de comentarios de la edicion, pero como vi que se habia echo un rollback pense que igual no le habia dado tiempo de leer el comentario que le deje o algo similar, se lo comente ahora en comtario pues no queria que se pensara que la edite sin cometarle nada. Saludos

Comment: Ahora me perdiste XD. Bueno, los tildes tienen solución. Voy a ver que editaste. Sin tildes. Lo de las IDE no veo tan relevante para IDE online, si el OP choca con problemas con una IDE en particular usando JavaFX creo que sería para una pregunta propia.

Comment: Como usted vea es su pregunta, yo solo queria que el OP lo pudiera probar y ver como funcionaba su respuesta, por eso le comente que si no le gustaba la idicion que hiciera un rollback sin problema. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel lo que parece es que usted solo queria figurar y protagonismo! ;)